WPF - Binding to Ancestor inside a different ItemSource works but results in error
I'm trying to Bind the foreground of a Label inside a DataTemplate to an Ancestor, this is the extract:
ViewModel Code
    public class DeviceOverview
    {
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string DeviceState { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DeviceOverview> DeviceOverviewList { get; set; }

This is the xaml:
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceOverviewList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel Margin="20,5,5,5">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding DeviceState, Converter={StaticResource ConvertStateToLed}}" Width="30"/>
                                        <Label Content="{Binding DeviceName}" Width="220" Margin="-60,0,0,0"
                                               Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.FontColor}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

The Window control has its own DataContext with his ViewModel and its property FontColor, and everything works. Still, i get the following error:

The FontColor property was not found in the DeviceOverview object.

Why do I get this error? And how do I can get rid of it?
Thanks

Judging by the error text, it is obvious that the Window Data Context contains an instance of DeviceOverview. Why this instance is there and not what you expect is impossible to say, since the code fragments and explanations you provided do not contain enough information.

The ItemControl is inside a UserControl. The Window object and UserControl object have different DataContext

@RiccardoPalma Show the relevant code parts. Do you get that error at runtime or in the XAML Designer?

In XAML designer, i'll try to extract only the relevant code

As a note, it is a bad idea that an ItemsControl in a UserControl has knowledge of a Window and its DataContext. The ItemsControl should only know its UserControl parent, but nothing above that in the element tree. Add a FontColor property to the UserControl and use that.

When you have the UserControl in XAML designer, its parent Window is of course not your MainWindow. Accessing an element outside the element tree of the UserControl is a severe design error.

Thank you for the tip! I'll take care of this aspect for my future implementation, in this case i have only one window containing few UserControl, so it is an exceptional case.

"Accessing an element outside the element tree of the UserControl is a severe design error" is nonsense. @RiccardoPalma there's nothing wrong with your design. Just because it's not one SO user's preferred way of doing things doesn't make it a "severe design error".

"The Window object and UserControl object have different DataContext" - it doesn't matter. Binding to the window data context works correctly for you. The problem is that in this Window Context there is not what you expect. You expect there an instance of a type that has the "FontColor" property. But in the Window data context there is an instance of "DeviceOverview" that does not have this property. Your problem is that somewhere you have reassigned the window data context. And this should not happen (for your implementation).

Regarding the overall layout architecture, I agree with @Clemens. Looking for ancestors above UserControl is a bad idea. It's better to create a dependency property in UserControl and explicitly pass the required context to it. Such an implementation will remove all ambiguities, simplify implementation and testing.

Reasoning on @Clemens design notes i discover that probably the problem is in the MainWindow XAML, where i define a default style for Label, so the Binding error is due to this default style.
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding FontColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

This style forces the Bind to search the FontColor property inside the Device Overview object.
This code solve everything:
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceOverviewList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel Margin="20,5,5,5">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding DeviceState, Converter={StaticResource ConvertStateToLed}}" Width="30"/>
                                        <Label Content="{Binding DeviceName}" Width="220" Margin="-60,0,0,0"
                                               Style="{x:Null}"
                                               Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.FontColor}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

Probably this post should be closed.

Assuming that FontColor is a property of your window's ViewModel, you have some errors in your binding declaration.
<Label Content="{Binding DeviceName}" 
       Width="220"
       Margin="-60,0,0,0"
       Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.FontColor}" />

Note also that Label.Foreground is a Brush not a Color and needs to be bound to an a property of that type, or use a value converter.

You mean FindAncestor and x:Type? Both is optional, and omitting it is not an error.

Thanks for the note, i'll change it. But your suggestion still doesnt work.
Yes, obviously FontColor is a Property of the Window DataContext .I don't understand why it's trying to resolve the binding inside the DeviceOverview object when the bind expression should tell it to look for it inside the Window DataDontext

@RiccardoPalma You do not have to change it. Your Binding expression is correct.

I see, but it seems to me that could be a formal (or syntax) issue, because the binding expression is solved and all the code works as expected..

"the code works as expected" is a clear indication that there is no format or syntax error at all. It is just the XAML designer where the parent Window of the UserControl is obviously not what you expect.
